# How to restrict users to download unity game file from react js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unity-game-engine, facebook-apps, server-side-rendering

I'm displaying a unity game in an iframe and I don't want to expose the game URL. How can I restrict the user to download game file? How facebook is handling this case? Is server-side rendering helps?

Comment: Can you give us a link to an example of a game that doesn't expose the game URL?

Comment: Sorry @Leo, as it is confidential I can't provide that

Comment: I mean.. a link to any game that does this.  I don't think anyone else does it.